# How to float elements inside a div tag

Tags: css

currently I have a list of events which looks like this:
[image]

Each event is placed inside its own div.

I want to put the first 4 lines on the left hand side and the Sport, Location, Date, Tickets Available and Ticket end date on the right hand side. (The side which "monitor my event" is on doesn't matter, center is fine too)

I tried to group them into div's with id="left and id="right" and then float using CSS, but that just messed everything up.

I have tried to put this html:

```
            <div class="boxed">
                <div id="left">
                    <h3><u><?php echo $event_id; ?></u></h3>
                    <h3><u><?php echo $event_name; ?></u></h3>
                    <h4>Hosted By <?php echo $username; ?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>

                    <?php
                    if($_SESSION["user_id"] != $event_user_id){ ?>
                    <h5><a href="ticket_booking.php?e_id=<?php echo $event_id ?>&e_date=<?php echo urlencode($event["event_date"]) ?>" class="link">Book Ticket</a></h5>
                    <?php } 
                    else{ ?>
                    <h5><a href="my_account.php" class="link">Monitor my event</a></h5>
                </div>
                <?php 
                    } 
                ?>

                <div id="right">
                    <h4>Sport: <?php echo $sport; ?></h4>
                    <h4>Location: <?php echo $location; ?></h4>  
                    <h4>Date: <?php echo $event_date; ?></h4>
                    <h4>Tickets available: <?php echo $number_of_tickets; ?></h4> 
                    <h4>Ticket end date: <?php echo $tick_end_date; ?></h4> 
                </div>
            </div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.boxed{
border: 2px solid blue;
}
#left {
float: left;
}
#right {
float: right;
}
```

But this was the result:
[image]

Comment: there has to be some CSS (otherwise your code wouldn't be displayed like this) -> post it, otherwise there's no way to answer your question.

Comment: This is a place to learn how to do your own work, not a place where others do it for you. You need to show us what you tried and we'll tell you what to read in order to learn what you need to know for getting your work done. Create a [mcve] of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are not defining width for `left` and `right`. Give them `width:50%;`

Also you should should change `id="left"` and `id="right"` to `class="left"` and `class="right"`, Otherwise there would be more than one elements with same id and that is not good.

In your php, when you run a while loop repeat `boxed` with `.left` and `.right` in it, Instead of keep adding `.left` and `.right` in a single `.boxed`, otherwise it won't look good.

One last thing I'm using `.boxed:after{}`, which is important when the content in it is positioned with `float` so that it clear them and does not cut their content short.

```css
.boxed{
  width:100%:
  margin:0;
  padding:5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:2px solid blue;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.left {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.right {
  width:50%:
  float:right;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.boxed:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxed">
   <div class="left">
     <h3><u>1</u></h3>
     <h3><u>Query's Football Event</u></h3>
     <h4>Hosted By Querty</h4>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>

     <h5><a href="ticket_booking.php" class="link">Book Ticket</a></h5>
     <h5><a href="my_account.php" class="link">Monitor my event</a></h5>
   </div>
   <div class="right">
     <h4>Sport: Football</h4>
     <h4>Location: Pnjnsasasn</h4>  
     <h4>Date: 19:01:16</h4>
     <h4>Tickets available: 59</h4> 
     <h4>Ticket end date: 17:01:16</h4> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="boxed">
   <div class="left">
     <h3><u>2</u></h3>
     <h3><u>Query's Football Event</u></h3>
     <h4>Hosted By Querty</h4>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>

     <h5><a href="ticket_booking.php" class="link">Book Ticket</a></h5>
     <h5><a href="my_account.php" class="link">Monitor my event</a></h5>
   </div>
   <div class="right">
     <h4>Sport: Football</h4>
     <h4>Location: Pnjnsasasn</h4>  
     <h4>Date: 19:01:16</h4>
     <h4>Tickets available: 59</h4> 
     <h4>Ticket end date: 17:01:16</h4> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend just using `text-align`. `div` elements are block level and will occupy the whole width so all you need to do is specify where you want the text oriented.

```
<div id="container">
  <div>asdf</div>
  <div>hjkl</div>
  <div>qwer</div>
</div>
```

```
#container div {
  background: blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

#container div:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
}

#container div:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s9Lxmh95/1/

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the "width", you should choose a specific or percent number to your divs so its look like this

http://www.byol.com.au/images/tutorial-dreamweaver-floating-div-fixed.gif